# Setting height to slider on the Swich

Tags: codenameone

On te Codename Designer I saw the Swith with a fine slider line, but when I use on a form, the circle and the slider are same Height.

¿how I must do to set the slider Height?

[Switch on Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1dmM.png)
[Switch on my Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMmpx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the difference between the styling of the `Switch` component in iOS and Android. They look different to match the platform native look. The designer lets you toggle iOS/Android native theme to see the difference.

You can explicitly override design styles in the `Switch` class to force a specific look. See: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/Switch.html

Comment: Solved, I add to the theme this Constants (switchThumbScaleY, switchTrackScaleY and switchTrackScaleX) Thanks